# PHP submit button not working.

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
header('Location: http://www.rate.ee');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my code. Very simple, isn't it. But it doesn't work and I don't get it.. I always thought that PHP only executes when I load the page, but the other page where I use same code works very well without JS..

Answer (score 9):

You need to wrap your button in a `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a form surrounding the input.

```
<body>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no form tag and even if you did it would need the method="post" attribute.

```php
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```